# Firebase Authentication with Facebook login has failed while the Facebook account has logged on

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

To my knowledge, all Facebook and Firebase connections are linked and all code should be functional. However, the authentication still isn't passing through Firebase, even though it is being logged on from Facebook.

**My Code:** ActMain.java

```
public class ActMain extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth fAuth;

/* Facebook */
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private static final String TAG = ActMain.class.getSimpleName();

/* onCreate */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_main);

    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Initialize Facebook Login button
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
        }
    });
}

/* Facebook */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    fAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(ActMain.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

I am totally lost on where to continue as it had worked before. Could I possibly be doing something very minor but due to that causing the authentication to fail?

Comment: Have you changed your build system?

Comment: How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Check your system hashkey is present in fb developer console or not!

Comment: Or try to build signed apk and check

Comment: I already have a hashkey present in FB Developer, however, I did do it for another project. Would that affect anything?

Comment: You need to have it for this package which you are talking about

Comment: Ok, then that is most likely the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the hashkey of your current package and put it on fb developer console.Then this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but the problem was that I am trying to login with same email on facebook & google so the email should be unique for each user.